# How can I extract the data of Registered Users?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

```
 public ActionResult Restaurants()
        {
            var restaurants = _context.ApplicationUsers.ToList();
            return View(restaurants);
        }
```

I want to extract the the information of registerd users from ASP.NET MVC and list it. But when I executed above code, I get error message of:

> Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets
>   'ApplicationUsers' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type
>   'ESportsScreening.Models.ApplicationUser'.

How can I list the informations of Registered users in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET does not allow you to have 2 `DbSet<T>`'s in the same context with the same entity type. The most likely cause of this error is initializing your `DbContext` like the following:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}
```

In the above code, `ApplicationDbContext` already contains a `DbSet` of type  `ApplicationUser` inherited from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` (which you can access through `_context.Users`). By manually adding a second `DbSet<ApplicationUser>`, we are creating 2 sets with the same entity type. Delete the manual `DbSet` property, and use the inherited `Users` set instead.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you have 2 objectsets of same type ESportsScreening.Models.ApplicationUser. You should remove one of them to resolve this error. You should only have one object set per type and you do not need more.

To help you find out how can you find registered users you need to provide some information about what are you considering as registered users. I guess all the users you have in your database are registered users in which case the following line of code is enough:

var restaurants = _context.ApplicationUsers.ToList();

In case you need to filter the users, you can use the Where extension method as follows:

var restaurants = _context.ApplicationUsers.Where( x=> yourconditionhere ).ToList();